# Periodic Task not running using Celery

Tags: celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have setup Celery to run a periodic task every 10 seconds that sends a post request to my Django Rest API Framework.

When I run the Celery worker it picks up the task correctly:

```
[tasks]
  . FutureForex.celery.debug_task
  . arbitrager.tasks.arb_data_post_request
```

When I run the beat nothing more gets logged and the POST request is not executed:

```
[2021-12-10 16:51:24,696: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
```

My tasks.py contains the following:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

import requests

app = Celery()

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls arb_data_post_request every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, arb_data_post_request.s(), name='arb_data_post_request')


@app.task
def arb_data_post_request():
    """
    Post request to the Django framework to pull the exchnage data and save to the database
    :return:
    """
    request = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/arbitrager/data/')
    logger.info(request.text)
```

I believe Celery is installed and setup correctly, as it finds the task. I can provide any settings if required though.
Any ideas as to why it doesn't kick off the task according to the scheduled 10 seconds would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Saul